# Here maps :load multiples KML files on differents map on same page and enable events on each

Tags: here-api

On the same page, i have differents maps loaded with Here maps API for each map i have loaded a specific kml file.

When i try to click, it works only on the last kml loaded and not others one, so how to make working event on each map ? This my code, it's taken from the example but a little bit modified :

```
function renderSchoenefeldAirport(map, ui, renderControls, kmlfile) {
// Create a reader object, that will load data from a KML file
var reader = new H.data.kml.Reader(kmlfile);

// Request document parsing. Parsing is an asynchronous operation.
reader.parse();

reader.addEventListener('statechange', function () {
// Wait till the KML document is fully loaded and parsed
if (this.getState() === H.data.AbstractReader.State.READY) {
  var parsedObjects = reader.getParsedObjects();
  // Create a group from our objects to easily zoom to them
  var container = new H.map.Group({objects: parsedObjects});

  // So let's zoom to them by default
  map.setViewBounds(parsedObjects[0].getBounds());

  // Let's make kml ballon visible by tap on its owner
  // Notice how we are using event delegation for it
  container.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target, position;

    // We need to calculated a position for our baloon
    if (target instanceof H.map.Polygon || target instanceof H.map.Polyline) {
      position = target.getBounds().getCenter();
    } else if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      position = target.getPosition();
    }
    if (position) {
      // Let's use out custom (non-api) function for displaying a baloon
      showKMLBallon(position, target.getData(), ui);
    }
  });

  // Make objects visible by adding them to the map
  map.addObject(container);
}
 });
}


/**
* Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
*/

// Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
'app_id': 'myappid',
'app_code': 'myappcode',
useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
});

// Step 2: initialize a map
// Please note, that default layer is set to satellite mode
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapcontainer1'), defaultLayers.satellite.map, {
  zoom: 1,
  pixelRatio: pixelRatio
});

var map_secondary = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapcontainer2'), defaultLayers.satellite.map, {
  zoom: 1,
  pixelRatio: pixelRatio
});

// Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

var behavior_secondary = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map_secondary));

// Template function for our controls
function renderControls(buttons) {
  var containerNode = document.createElement('div');
  containerNode.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:#fff; padding:10px;');
  containerNode.className = "btn-group";

  Object.keys(buttons).forEach(function (label) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = label;
    input.type = 'button';
    input.onclick = buttons[label];
    input.className="btn btn-sm btn-default"
    containerNode.appendChild(input);
  });

  map.getElement().appendChild(containerNode);
}

function showKMLBallon(position, data, ui) {
  var content = data.balloonStyle.text;
  if (content) {
    // Styling of the balloon text.
    // The only supported wilde cards are $[text] and $[description].
    content = content
      .replace('$[name]', data.name || '')
      .replace('$[description]', data.description || '');

    // Note how we are caching our infoBubble instance
    // We create InfoBubble object only once and then reuse it
    var bubble = showKMLBallon.infoBubble;
    if (!bubble) {
      bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(position, {content: content});
      ui.addBubble(bubble);
      bubble.getContentElement().style.marginRight = "-24px";
      // Cache our instance for future use
      showKMLBallon.infoBubble = bubble;
    } else {
      bubble.setPosition(position);
      bubble.setContent(content);
      bubble.open();
    }
  }
}

// Step 4: create the default UI component, for displaying bubbles
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

var ui_secondary = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map_secondary, defaultLayers);

// Step 5: main logic goes here
renderSchoenefeldAirport(map, ui, renderControls, 'path/to/file1.kml');

   renderSchoenefeldAirport(map_secondary, ui_secondary, renderControls, 'path/to/file2.kml');
```

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

In the provided snippet there is a line 106: var bubble = showKMLBallon.infoBubble; where the info bubble is "cached", the problem is that when the user clicks on one of the maps the infobubble is created and cached, and when somebody clicks on the second map the the info bubble from the first is used.

In the simplest case this line should be:
var bubble = ui.infoBubble;

so the bubble for each map instance in cached. In general, depending on the desired outcome, the proper caching strategy should be devised.

Hope this helps.